# Is there any way to have Cygwin tools in PATH without them replacing Windows commands?

Tags: windows, cygwin, environment-variables, path

I would like to be able to use GDB, GCC and such straight out of a windows command prompt, so I put my Cygwin bin directory in my Windows path. Problem is that Cygwin programs now take priority over windows programs. Is there any way to keep the cygwin binaries in the path but make them the lowest priority? Lower priority than system32 and other OS folders?

Comment: Scratch my PWD example. It isn't a windows command anyway, but the principle is there. Would be nice to see if anyone can think of a way around it.

Answer (score 2):

I fairly certain Windows places precedence of the the `Path` environment variable entries from first to last.  If the Cygwin folder is last in the variable, then it would search that folder last for executables.